# Delete unused kafka consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Apache Kafka 0.10 with a compacted topic as a **distributed cache synch mechanism**. When the application starts up it generates an instance specific `consumer group id`. As instances are added and removed for horizontal scalability, obviously we get a large number of group ids that should never be used again.

I'm sure that this is the perfect use case for `KStreams` and `KTables`, but I am trying to do this myself for intellectual reasons as well as that the `KStreams` and `KTables` are defined as alpha quality in 0.10.

Is there a Kafka API call that I can use that could delete an existing consumer group, knowing that it should never be used again?

Since Zookeeper is not maintaining consumer offsets in version 0.10, Is there a way delete the consumer group using Kafka?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Kafka 0.9, an internal topic is used to store committed offsets. You can configure how long those offsets should be kept via `offsets.retention.minutes`. (See also `offsets.retention.check.interval.ms`).

Comment: It's not the offsets that I am worried about. It's the possibly large number of consumer groups showing up in monitor tooling. If my application creates a consumer group, and my application knows to delete the consumer group. Then I would think that there could be an api call to do it. Maybe a feature request?

Comment: AFAIK, the monitoring tool reads the offset-log to collect the information it shows. Thus, I would assume, that deleting the offsets is the same a deleting the consumer group.

Comment: ... and the default value of the `offsets.retention.minutes` is `1440`, 24 hours. A nice explanation is available by [docs.confluent.io](https://docs.confluent.io/3.3.0/streams/faq.html#why-is-my-application-re-processing-data-from-the-beginning).

Comment: The default value for offsets.retention.minutes has increased to 7 days fyi

Answer (score 7):

> **It's possible with CLI** in Kafka

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups \
    --bootstrap-server <bootstrap_server(s)> \
    --topic <topic_name> \
    --delete \
    --group <consumer_group_name>
```

`kafka-consumer-groups` should be available in Kafka installation home.